# Test custom ERC20 token with MEW

Tags: solidity, tokens, remix, myetherwallet

Before the question, I want to list my development environment configuration:

- I am using Remix online solidity IDE for coding
- My contract is running on local PC with RPC (web3 provider option in Remix)
- I set up MEW to run on my http:127.0.0.1:8545 node

I managed to deploy my ERC20 token contract, adding it to the MEW list that displays the current amount on that account; however, even though in the contract I set 10000000 as the initial supply of tokens, MEW displays '0.000 1e-11 RC' as the total amount. **What am I missing out?**

The code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract UnclearlyToken {

    string public constant name = "Unclearly";
    string public constant symbol = "UC";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    uint totalAmount = 10000000;

    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint _value);

    function UnclearlyToken() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalAmount;
    }

    function totalSupply() constant returns(uint) {
        return totalAmount;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns(uint256) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success) {
        if(balances[msg.sender] >= _value 
            && _value > 0 
            && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {

            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success) {
        if(balances[_from] >= _value
            && _value > 0 
            && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]
            && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value) {

            balances[_from] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;
            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }
}
```

MEW side:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, sorry for the question, it's quite simple. You just need to change the decimals of your token. See this discussion for more details: [Float not allowed in solidity vs decimal places asked for token contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9256/float-not-allowed-in-solidity-vs-decimal-places-asked-for-token-contract)

Comment: Hi there. If you think your question will be useful to other people in future, can you add a few more details to your answer to make it clearer what you did to solve the problem? :-)

Comment: Sure, just a min.